# CSS3 Translate multiple times?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, translate-animation

My basic scene is like so:
[image]

- Step 1: Move red box to left hand side, out of viewport.
- Step 2: Then, instantly move red box back to start position, without any animation.

I don't know how to accomplish this exactly as I want.

**My code is as follows:**

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  animation: nudge 5s linear;
}
@keyframes nudge {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-5650px, 155px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I had created a snippet based on the code you had provided and added it to question for better visualization of the issue. Hope you don't mind. If you do, please feel free to roll it back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations by default work that way. That is, the element would immediately snap back to its original position after the animation is completed (unless `animation-fill-mode` is set as `forwards`).

Your problem is with the `keyframes` setting. When you set the transform to happen at `50%` and your initial `transform` state is null, the element would gradually move from original position (no transform) to translated position for the first 50% of the animation and then gradually move back again from the end position to the original for the next 50%. You can avoid it by setting the keyframe at `100%` instead.

```css
.box {
   background: red;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   animation: nudge 5s linear;
}

@keyframes nudge {  
   100% {
      transform: translate(-5650px, 155px);
   } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you Harry. One last thing if you have a sec. Any idea why this doesn't work in safari? (I have added prefixes)

Comment: @KeithDonegan: You are welcome. Nice to know that it helped. Regarding the Safari part, I am a bit stumped too. It should work in the recent versions of Safari as both `transform` and `keyframes` are supported by it. Don't have Safari installed to check though. Can you tell me which version you are using and I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: Sure thing. Version 8

Comment: @KeithDonegan: Could find nothing mate. I hope you've add prefixes for the `transform` within the `keyframes` also (because Safari 8 still needs it). Other than that maybe try changing `100%` to `to` (both have same effect).

Answer (score 3):

Use `100% {transform: translate(-5650px, 155px);}` instead of `50% {transform: translate(-5650px, 155px);}`

```css
.box {
   background: red;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   animation: 
   nudge 2s linear;
}

@keyframes nudge {  
   100% {
      transform: translate(-2560px, 155px);
   } 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```